# Increase the efficiency of K-complementary pairs of array into O(NlogN)

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

I want to implement efficient method of  K-complementary pairs of  array of integers match with  O(NlogN). Below is my code and it is not working. Could anybody help me to resolve this. I have tried it but cannot sort out by myself

```
public static StringBuffer newFunction(int arr[], int k) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int result = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int j = arr.length - 1;
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= j) {
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] == k) {
            sb.append("{" + arr[i] + "," + arr[j] + "}" + ", ");
            result++;
        } else if ((arr[i] + arr[j]) < k) {
            i++;
        } else {
            j--;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
    return sb;
}
```

Comment: How do you want to handle identical pairs? Should `newFunction(new int[] {1, 1, 2, 2, 2}, 3)` print `1` or `6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the increment & decrement of the indices when you find a pair. The relevant code modified below:

```
while (i <= j) {
    if (arr[i] + arr[j] == k) {
        sb.append("{" + arr[i] + "," + arr[j] + "}" + ", ");
        result++;
        i++; // increment
        j--; // decrement
    } else if ((arr[i] + arr[j]) < k) {
        i++;
    } else {
        j--;
    }
}
```

With this modification it's supposed to work:

```
int myArray[] = {8,5,7,10,2,13,11,4,9,6,1,3};
System.out.println(newFunction(myArray, 15));
// 5
// {2,13}, {4,11}, {5,10}, {6,9}, {7,8},
```

Comment: Thanks... I understood it.

Comment: Note that this code prints `2` for the array `{1, 1, 2, 2, 2}` and `k = 3`, which is probably not the desired answer.

Comment: Sandipan I need to make sure whether my complexity calculation is correct aith above above code. I guess it would be O(NlogN) is it correct...?

Comment: @Dilee yes it's going to be dominated by the sorting algorithm which is O(NlogN), although your pair searchign is O(N), the total complexity is O(NlogN) + O(N) = O(NlogN)

Comment: as mentioned by user3290797 in the above comment. It doesn't work well for {1, 1, 2, 2, 2} and k=3. How can we sort out this ?

Comment: your algorithm should output `{1,2}, {1,2}`, now what do you want to output in this case?

Comment: if you want each unique pair to be present once in output keep a hashset of pairs and before inserting a new pair into `sb1 with `sb.append` ensure it's not already present in the hash set.

Comment: Sandipan Don't we want to have many pairs instead of {1,2}, {1,2}. Please re correct me I am wrong

Comment: it depends upon your requirement: you send to send as many pairs as possible or only unique pairs.